# How do you pass perameter from a view to a controller function using ajax

Tags: c#, ajax

I have a view with a button to call `ajax` but now need to include a parameter `new { DNumber = item.DrawingNumber }` and have that passed into the controller via `ajax`.  What do I need to add to my code to make this work please?

view:
PDF

```
<script>
    function OpenDrawingPDF() {
     $.ajax({
              url: "OpenDrawingPDF",
              success: function () { alert("success"); } 
            });
       return false;
    } 
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public void OpenDrawingPDF(string DNumber)
{
    string Path = @"\\Serv1\Company\10 - Production\Production Drawings\CAD pdf\";

    if (Directory.Exists(Path))
    {
        string Folder = DNumber.Substring(4, 2) + @"\";

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path + Folder + DNumber + ".pdf");
    }
}
```

Comment: Parameters are either at the end of a URL following a question mark and separated by ampersands. Or added as a HTTP Header (could be a custom header).  Parameters on a URL are not encrypted while HTTP headers are encrypted when HTTPS is used.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following approach. Provide your Id to your element holding a DBNumber and then access it from your function:

```
var dbNumber = $('#dbNumberItemId').val();
$.ajax({
    url: "OpenDrawingPDF",
    type: "Get", // I assume that you are sending get request
    data: { 
        dbNumber: dbNumber
    },
    ...
 });
```

Comment: @ Serhii - I have got this working but I'm not sure how to get the var dbNumber = $('#dbNumberItemId').val() for the actual table row that the button is on.

Comment: <td>
                                    @if (item.DrawingNumber.Contains("CAD") || (item.DrawingNumber.Contains("DRG")))
                                    {
                                        <button type="submit" id="dbNumberItemId" value="@item.DrawingNumber" onclick="return myPDF();">PDF</button>
                                    }
                                </td>

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution that worked for me:

view:

```
<a id="myid" data-mydata1=@item.DrawingNumber href="javascript:" onclick="myPDF('tblCircuitDiagrams', this)">PDF</a>

<script>
    function myPDF(table, value) {

        var mydata = document.querySelector('#myid');

        var dbNumber = value.dataset.mydata1;

        $.ajax({
            url: "OpenDrawingPDF",
            data: { DNumber : dbNumber },
            cache: false,
            type: "GET"
        });
    }
</script>
```

controller:

```
public void OpenDrawingPDF(string DNumber)
{
    string Path = @"\\serv1\Company\10 - Production\Production Drawings\CAD pdf\";

    if (DNumber != null && Directory.Exists(Path))
    {
        string Folder = DNumber.Substring(4, 2) + @"\";

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path + Folder + DNumber + ".pdf");
    }

}
```